# INotifyPropertyChanged wont pass through View Model

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I am making a WinForms program, with an architectural pattern quite similar to [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel). The main difference is that class I am using as model, also acts as a user control. I know this might not be the most awesome setup, but it is what I have to work with.

> The problem is, that when the property in the model is changed, the change isn't reflected in the view...

I am suspecting that I haven't implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly, but I can't really see anything wrong. I hope you guys can...

**Model**

```
public partial class ModelAndUserControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private decimal _price;

    public ModelAndUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    // Changes in this property, should be reflected in the view
    public decimal Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Price");
        }
    }
}
```

**View-Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private readonly MyView view;
    private ModelAndUserControl model;

    public MyViewModel(MyView view, ModelAndUserControl model) 
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
    }

    // Debugging reveals that the value of the formatted 
    // string, changes correctly when the model property changes.
    // But the change isn't reflected in the view.
    public string FormattedPrice
    {
        get { return string.format("{0:n0} EUR", model.Price); }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public partial class MyView : UserControl
{
    private MyViewModel viewModel;

    public MyView() 
    {
        InitializeComponent(ModelAndUserConrol model);

        // Create an instance of the view model
        viewModel = new MyViewModel(this, model);

        // Create the data binding to the price
        txtPrice.DataBindings.Add("Text", viewModel, nameof(viewModel.FormattedPrice));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are notifying that `Price` changed, but not taht `FormattedPrice` changed

Comment: Actually both of them changed. But it was my understanding that if the base property (in this case `Price`) changed, then all "derived" properties would be covered by the base notification?

Comment: No, your databinding only listens for `FormattedPrice` changing. You either have to bubble up the `PropertyChangedEvent` by subscribing in your viewmodel and raising it for `FormattedPrice` or scratch the `FormattedPrice`, subscribe to `Price` and do formatting in the view.

Comment: I would prefer not to bind directly to the model, as this causes some other issues. More specifically, if I change then model to a new instance, I have to redo all the data bindings. I wanted to avoid this, by binding to the view-model.

Comment: Then you need `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your viewmodel and raise it for your formatted properties when model changes below.

Comment: Is there anyway to listen for the `PropertyChanged` (invoked by the model) in the View-Model and then implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` based on that?

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Mats391/c3dbf1cb6bba71351fa54a07cbe91db3)

Comment: Thank you @Mats391, that works perfectly. If you want, you can submit it as an actual answer. Then I can accept it.

Comment: `ModelAndUserControl : UserControl` Referencing UI in your VM or model isn't MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to raise `PropertyChanged` on the view model you bind to or the binding wont know when to update. To raise `PropertyChanged` on your `FormattedPrice` property when the model changes you can do something like this.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly MyView view;
    private ModelAndUserControl model;

    public MyViewModel(MyView view, ModelAndUserControl model) 
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
        this.model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
    }

    // Debugging reveals that the value of the formatted 
    // string, changes correctly when the model property changes.
    // But the change isn't reflected in the view.
    public string FormattedPrice
    {
        get { return string.format("{0:n0} EUR", model.Price); }
    }

    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.PropertyName){
            case "Price":
                InvokePropertyChanged("FormattedPrice");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged        
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```